# when trying if condition in python getting an error

Tags: python

Hi am very new to python when am trying below if condition am getting an error.

```
>>> age=18
>>> if age>18:
... print "Elligible for voting"
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print "Elligible for voting"
```

Comment: Indentation error most likely

Comment: Which version of python are you using? And please correct formatting (it may be problem with indentation)

Comment: Please show the entire traceback for the error.

Answer (score 2):

In Python [indentation is very important](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).  After `if` statements, you need indentation for whatever the `if` statement is supposed to do if it evaluates to `True`:

This is most likely your complete traceback:

```
>>> if age>18:
... print "Elligible for voting"
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print "Elligible for voting"
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

So it is telling you the cause of your error, an indented block is expected, but you have not given one.

Try:

```
>>> if age>18:
...     print "Elligible for voting"
...
```

Which is syntactically correct.